# How to install phpwkhtmltopdf without composer?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

On our production server we are still running **PHP 5.3.1**.
**Composer** (https://getcomposer.org/) needs **PHP 5.3.2** - so close and still so far...

The only documented way to install ***phpwkhtmltopdf*** (https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf) is to use **Composer**.

So is there any way to install **phpwkhtmltopdf** without using **Composer**?

*It's just a small wrapper for **wkhtmltopdf**(http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), so i think it should be possible.*

thanks for any help!

Comment: install it locally with composer then upload it to your server.

Comment: @cmorrissey this does work? i thought it's checking dependencies and stuff in its environment. it seems to require the Composer-autoloader as well.

Comment: @cmorrissey ok, this does work! - thank you very much! if you post this as an answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your sever doesn't have the required PHP version to run composer you can run/install components locally and then upload them to your server ... with the caveat that the package you are installing doesn't have the same PHP version requirements that composer does.